# Autenticación Nestjs y Angular error 401 en otra ruta

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una autenticación para angular, el backend es NestJS, es mi primera vez haciendo backend, ya implementé las estrategias y todo funciona bien, ingreso a mi aplicación con mi usuario establecido, el problema es que me sale esto al ingresar a la ruta dónde realizo el crud de roles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que el error es que no está autorizado y que está mal el token, pero realizo el login sin problemas.

*Soy frontEnd jr y decidí hacer backend, disculpas si no formule bien la pregunta, es mi segunda vez :(

Comment: Podrían ser los [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)? [Activar CORS en el backend NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors)

Comment: Como estas pasando el login en la petición?

Comment: Me refiero a como le estas pegando al post del login.

Comment: El error "jwt malformed" se debe a que no estas enviando un JWT valido, revisa que el token que envías sea un string de tres partes delimitado por puntos como el siguiente. `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`